# Revert lettuce to vegetative phase by cutting it down

Tags: vegetables, plant-care, growth, flowering, cuttings

I have read several article stating that it is possible to revert a bolted leafy lettuce to vegetative growth by cutting it down to 1 centimeter.

Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, yes, it works, so if yours has bolted, it's worth a try, you've nothing to lose, its either cut back or rip the plant out. Depending where you live though, you may have to wait for cooler weather conditions to see any useful growth.

Comment: thank you very much! do you know what factors are most important when trying to revert it to the vegetative stage?

Comment: Nothing really,  other than supplying water if its dry  - just cut it down low and wait and see what happens